# Autoware building error

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros

While trying to build Autoware, following [this guide](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware), the following errors appear, as seen in the image:

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions as to how I could fix this? I've already re-installed ROS and Catkin tools.

The contents of env.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  /bin/echo "Usage: env.sh COMMANDS"
  /bin/echo "Calling env.sh without arguments is not supported anymore. 
Instead spawn a subshell and source a setup file manually."
  exit 1
fi

# ensure to not use different shell type which was set before
CATKIN_SHELL=sh

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(cd "`dirname "$0"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Read your own output "bad variable name" on line 4 of `env.sh`

Comment: I've tried looking into it, but I don't really understand it, I'm editing the post so that it'd include the contents of this file.

Comment: That file is sourcing `. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"`, so you'd have to see what's going on there too. In general I'd say this build script can't handle filenames with spaces in it. `Files/Microsoft` looks suspiciously like `Program Files/Microsoft`.